# How can I get access to StackOverflow data?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I need to create reports around tag usage and unanswered posts. What're the different mechanisms available to access this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 options:

1. Use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (Stack Exchange Data Explorer), which allows you to easily query the data. You can download the queried rows, however it does not allow you to run queries locally and can only be used manually.
2. Use [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), which allows you to query some things of Stack Overflow over REST calls.
3. Download a public release of the SO [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and use historical data.
4. Use the [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/) [public dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data) on Google BigQuery

Comment: There are (now) 4 options.  [Announcing Stack Overflow Data on Google’s BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/)

Comment: Awesome, nice to hear that.